# adding frames to mainFrame

Tags: java, swing, mdi, jinternalframe

i want to add some frame to my main frame, lets say we've 3 frames (Frame1, Frame2, and Frame3) i want to:

1. Create new `Frame` called Frame 4 and add menu bar with items (View Frame1, View Frame2, View Frame3) --> actually i've created this frame successfully.
2. When click on View Frame1 i want to display Frame1 in a certain place in Frame4 and so on for all menuItems
3. My problem is i've created my old frames by using Drag-and-drop tech. in net beans
4. There is a component called internalFrame but when i tried to use it i couldn't add my old frame to this internal one.

Comment: Use one [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and multiple [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)s instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problems by reading [this great tutorial](http://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/creating-mdi-applications-in-java-using-netbeans/) on creating MDI applications in Java using NetBeans.