# waiting to return from JFrame 2 to continue some statements execution in JFrame 1

Tags: java, swing, jframe

let's say that i have 2 JFrames (A) & (B)

Frame (A) fires Frame (B), as follows

```
line 1: private void fun1()
line 2: {
line 3:      new B();
line 4:      Do something
line 5: }
```

in line 3 i activate frame B.. i don't wanna go-to line 4 until i turn back from JFrame (B)
becuase according to some actions in Frame (B) i do some action like this

```
new (B);
container.add(JPanel);
```

`container.add(JPanel);` --> depends on a flag fired from JFrame (B)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/758280

Comment: @Jeffrey Unfortunately, this has all been [said before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885784/adding-frames-to-mainframe) to the OP with no apparent effect.  Maybe if they hear it coming from **3** other people, it will sink in.

Comment: Ok let's say that i've changed JFrame (B) to JDialog ... this dialog is a custom Dialog... i've 3 butttons Add, Reset, and cancel... i want tp show my Dialog from Frame (A) and do nothing until the user in Dialog (B) "which should be always in the top" clicks Add... then according to that action i'm gonna add a certain panel in Frame (A)

Comment: my question is: How could i wait for the user to click on add in dialog (B) to turn back to mainFrame (A) and to add the panel it explained before..

Comment: what would be the call from Frame (A)

Comment: This is how modal dialogs work. The main GUI's code essentially stops from the moment you set the modal dialog as visible. Then the main GUI's code will not resume until the modal dialog is no longer visible. Swing does all of this automatically for you -- Try it and see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using a [modal dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) to display the contents of frame B.

Comment: Don't even consider -- just do it, because this is the correct answer. Don't  use a second JFrame, but use a modal JDialog for the second window. 1+ up-vote.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Unfortunately, this has all been [said before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885784/adding-frames-to-mainframe) to the OP with no apparent effect.  Maybe if they hear it coming from **3** other people, it will sink in.